# I'm trying to understand if using :target in css to handle page functionality is a good idea or a bad one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, menu

So I've recently used this tutorial [cssPanelMenu](http://css-tricks.com/off-canvas-menu-with-css-target/) to create a similar menu that drops down from the top of a page when the page is in a mobile size. However, something about the technique is rubbing me the wrong way. It seems ... inappropriate ...to implement certain pieces of functionality by basically using hashtag routing.

But I'm not sure if I'm just being a little old-fashioned. I've Googled whether or not there are any particular drawbacks to approaching a menu this way - but I haven't really come across anything.

So my question is can anyone speak to this technique as being something that is inline with best practices - or something that is not?

Thank you so much for your time and help!

Comment: It's comon practise in single page web apps. And it's not really a "hashtag" symbol - any of hash, pound (in the US) or octothorpe would be more accurate.

Comment: I think the one drawback is if you need support for IE8 users, target fails completely.  I use this method in a phonegap app though and it's brilliant -- lightweight, smooth, no js -- and since the app is for mobile users I know there's no need for IE8 support.

Comment: it can cause history pollution, making the back button unpredictable if you don't fully implement onhashchange() as well. it's ok to jump between sections, but every little action shouldn't mod the url...